# setup project templete in visual studio express 2010 unavailable ..then how to do

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a executable file in visual studio express 2010 .But the  setup project template is not present in visual studio express 2010. So, how should  I proceed?

Comment: The Express edition is a "learning" edition, it is very short on practical tooling you need to support customers.  You'll have to go shopping for an installer creator utility, there are many around.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this Extension to your Visual Studio.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspxt

Otherwise you can use the Publish Project option from the Visual Studio to create the required Setup file and then share it to other users. They can install your software then. :)